# Is it possible to create a Wix Burn Bootstrapper specifying non-existent chain msipackages

Tags: wix, burn

I'm trying to find out if it is possible to create a burn bootstrapper exe where the chain bundle references non-existent msi packages.  In this scenario I'll be using the compressed="no" attribute so the set of msi packages I want installing will not be embedded but will be alongside the bootstrapper.exe

However at the time of compiling the bootstrapper.exe the msi packages to be installed do not yet exist - However they will do at a later date...

The msi packages have well known names that won't change, and will live in a well known location relative to the bootstrapper.exe - they just arent available at compilation time.

Does anyone know if this is possible with wix burn?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is impossible - but - you may use some "placeholder" msi files - just for sake of compilation. 
Of course if you do so- the data that the bootstrapper builds-up - like the msi installation sizes, the msi file sizes, the feature lists and so on will not ba avialable...

Comment: Doesn't sound like placeholder msi files are a viable workaround if it means incorrect metadata - this needs to be professional.  I guess if burn is collecting this type of data then you are right that what I'd like is not possible.